# How Can I Make a View, With a Tab View in It, Scrollable?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, xcode11

I got an NSTabView inside an NSView. That NSView is in an NSClipView, which in turn is in an NSScrollView. It looks like this (NSTabView in green, and NSView in red):

[image]

As you can see, the content of NSTabView gets clipped, and no scrollbars appear (since the view doesn't expand beyond the window).

How can I make NSTabView take up as much space as it needs (doesn't clip out), and expand the NSView with it? Then, NSScrollView can deal with the scrolling of the overgrown NSView.

Since my content changes dynamically, I don't want to put in some hard values for the width and height of NSTabView's superview.

This is only part of it; here's now the overall hierarchy looks:

[image]

I want the NSTabView's superview to be scrollable instead of clipping out, like this:

[image]

Comment: How have you set-up the scroll view?  [This](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextUILayer/Tasks/TextInScrollView.html) should give some clues.

Comment: I set the constraints so that the NSTabView expands right inside its superview. Its superview is in the clip view of the scroll view. However, this causes NSTabView to expand as much as there is space in its superview, clipping its content. I don't want the content to be clipped out; instead, I want NSTabView to take up as much space as it needs without clipping its content. How can I do that? I read the documentation already, still clueless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup I'll describe is for an `NSTabView` that will pin to the top, left, and right sides of the scroll view. Note the `NSTabView` could be replaced with any other `NSView`, the setup is the same.

[image]

Starting with you putting a scroll view into the xib/storyboard, you'll have `NSScrollView -> NSClipView -> NSView (document view)`. Constrain the NSScrollView to the edges of the window. Drop your `NSTabView` onto the `NSView` instance. Add constraints so that your `NSTabView` edge constraints equal the `NSView` and define a height constraint either explicitly or implicitly with other content inside the tab view that defines it.

[image]

Personally I like to change the `NSView` instance (document view) layout to use constraints, by default it uses autoresizing masks and this makes it difficult to keep it in sync with the NSTabView. We want the document view to be pinned to the top, left, and right sides of the scroll view. The size of this view is what determines the scrollable region so we want it to be the same size as the NSTabView so the height of the tab view will determine the scrollable area.

To change this, select the document view, and under the Size Inspector we want to change the "Layout" type to "Automatic".

[image]

Lastly, add constraints to the top, left, and right and you should be good to go.

If you want the scroll view to start at the top rather than the bottom, you should subclass the document view and override `isFlipped`:

```swift
class FlippedView: NSView {
    override var isFlipped: Bool { true }
}
```

Comment: Using constraints to pin that document view onto the top, left, and right of the clip view did the job for me! I didn't even think of setting the document view's layout to "automatic"! Thank you so much, really appreciated your help.